# textmining, Export clusters in Rapidminer

Tags: export, cluster-analysis, rapidminer

I am working with approximately 300 articles (txt-files), and my cluster-analysis has so far been successful.

Now I wish to save/export these 5 clusters separately, so that I can do further analysis on each cluster.

How is that possible?

I would appreciate any answer!

/LK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could export the result of the clustering operation to Excel and examine the results using this.

Alternatively, you could use the `Filter Examples` operator with a suitable filter to create example sets for specific values of the cluster attribute.

Comment: Thank you. Maybe this follow up is redundant. But is it possible to save each cluster separately in my repository.

Comment: Yes - the result of filtering is an example set that can be stored in the repository.

Comment: Perhaps the original poster could up vote this if it is a useful answer?